# How to use Model in diffrent controller with ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new new ROR and i am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3 version

I want to use Model in different controller.

For ex: My Controller name `PackagesController` and I want use `OrderHistory` Model in `PackagesController`.

See below code

```
class PackagesController < ApplicationController

   def paypal
      @data = params
      #User.create(:name => "user1",:address=>"address1")
      @package_id   = @data[:pid]
      @package_price    = @data[:pprice]

      OrderHistory.create(:admin_user_id => "1", :package_id=>package_id, :price=>package_price, :payment_status=>'pending' )
  end
end
```

This code very time given error **`uninitialized constant PackagesController::OrderHistory`**

Please help

Comment: `include OrderHistory`? You should create `OrderHistory` in the `OrderHistoryController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any model in any controller. The problem elsewhere

Make sure that you have model class named OrderHistory saved in the file named order_history.rb

Comment: yes i am sure my model class name is correct. see class OrderHistroy < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: OrderHistroy vs OrderHistory